# creating subclass instances from base class

Tags: java, reflection

I have a number of typed exceptions which all share the same characteristic: they hold a status (int) field which is always non-zero. The code typically checks for a status variable and if that is non-zero throws the corresponding exception (depending on the context). I.e.:

```
if (status != 0) throw new AStatusException(status);
... // other context
if (status != 0) throw new BStatusException(status);
... // other context
if (status != 0) throw new CStatusException(status);
```

Mostly out of curiusity I thought I might implement this common functionality in a static method `throwIfNotZero` of a base class `StatusException` and have the various `A, B, CStatusException` classes all inherit that class. This would hopefully allow me to write code like this:

```
AStatusException.throwIfNonZero(status);
... // other context
BStatusException.throwIfNonZero(status);
... // other context
CStatusException.throwIfNonZero(status);
```

Sadly, the closest I got is the code I append at the end of the post, which is not very satisfactory. Is there a better way to do it, perhaps without using Reflection and / or avoiding the requirement to pass the class instance which appears redundant (see 'usage')?

#### Base Exception

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class StatusException extends Exception {
    public int status;
    public StatusException (int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public static <T extends StatusException> void raiseIfNotZero(Class<T> klass, int code) throws T{
        try {
            if (code != 0) throw klass.getConstructor(Integer.TYPE).newInstance(code);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

#### usage:

```
AStatusException.raiseIfNotZero(AStatusException.class, status);
BStatusException.raiseIfNotZero(BStatusException.class, status);
```

Comment: Sadly static methods in java are not inherited. Hence when you invoke AStatusException you are actually statically bound to the static method in StatusException, which does not hold any information about which concrete subclass you are referencing.

Comment: One way to go is not being DRY and repeat the static raiseIfNotZero method in every concrete class, since the code is not really that big if you remove the reflection hassle. However it's an ugly code repetition.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload function raiseIfNotZero() in the super class StatusException.

And call it like this

```
StatusException.raiseIfNotZero(AStatusException.class, status);
StatusException.raiseIfNotZero(BStatusException.class, status);
```

Comment: Yeah, I can do that with the existing code as it is .. the thing is I was hoping for a way to only specify the subclass only once and avoid having to pass the class object.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int final STATUS_EXCEPTION_A=1;
public static int final STATUS_EXCEPTION_A=2;


raiseIfNotZero(int type, int status)
{
   switch(type)
   { case STATUS_EXCEPTION_A: throw new AStatusException(); break;
     case STATUS_EXCEPTION_B: throw new BStatusException(); break;
     ...
   }
}
```